# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in another submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read a couple of threads on StackOverflow but did not find any answer that has fixed my problem. I'm pretty new to Python and cannot figure out how does modeling system works. I do understand the difference between module and package, but that does not help me with my problem. Here goes:

Here's my project structure:

```
venv/
root/
    commons/
        config.py
    main/
        main.py
```

Here's my `config.py`:

```
class Config:
...
```

Here's my `main.py`

```
from commons.config import Config
...
```

when running `(venv) python3 root/main/main.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`. What am I doing wrong? It is a problem with my app? with my `main.py`? With the way I execute my `main.py`?

Execution is done using Python 3.9 on MacOS

Comment: Try `from ..commons.config import Config`. Another option is to put an `__init__.py` in `root`.

Comment: I do have an empty `__init__.py` in `root`. But this does not help

Comment: Is `root` in the python path?

Answer (score 1):

The path to `config.py` is not added to the list of paths where the interpreter looks for modules and hence does find the `config` module.

A simple workaround is to change in `main.py`:

```
from commons.config import Config
```

to

```
from root.commons.config import Config
```

and execute `main.py` as a module in the project directory with

```
python -m root.main.main
```

When the file is executed as a module it will add the path from where it is executed to the paths the interpreter looks for modules and `root.commons.config` is a absolute reference from then on.

Answer (score 0):

As @Iliya mentioned, the interpreter doesn't find the way to `'config'` module.

You can modify your `main.py` to fix the issue:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("absolute_path_to_root")

from commons.config import Config
...
```

or

```
import os
import sys

# set the parent dir into python's search path
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)

from commons.config import Config
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After carefully browsing StackOverflow I finally managed to find a solution that works for me using `setup.py`.
Thank you [@np8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3015186/np8) for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/3082471)